# Trying to write a TypeScript definition file — JSX element type 'SideMenu' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to write a type definition file for [react-native-side-menu](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-side-menu), to declare it. I'm using it in a TypeScript project but it has not TypeScript definitions.

Usually what works for me is to do:

```
declare module 'react-native-side-menu' {
  export class SideMenu {any}
}
```

This works for many other libraries, but for this one I get:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --alwaysStrict --skipLibCheck --watch

[12:37:41] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

app/views/Movies.tsx:85:8 - error TS2604: JSX element type 'SideMenu' does not have any construct or call signatures.

85       <SideMenu menu={menu}>
          ~~~~~~~~


app/views/Actors.tsx:80:8 - error TS2604: JSX element type 'SideMenu' does not have any construct or call signatures.

80       <SideMenu menu={menu}>
          ~~~~~~~~


[12:37:41] Found 2 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

(I'm using it this way: `import SideMenu from 'react-native-side-menu'` and it works properly in the application. I just want to remove the TypeScript error message.)

**How to declare this module properly with TypeScript?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was missing a `default` (as in `export default class ...`). My final solution:

```
declare module 'react-native-side-menu' {
  import { Component } from 'react'

  export default class SideMenu extends Component<any,any>{any}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need `any` inside your class body. In fact, it will result in an error.
2. You don't need the type parameters neither — `{}` are the default values.
3. If you know what props `SideMenu` accepts, you can describe them inside your declaration (here: `Props`).

**`react-native-side-menu.d.ts`**

```
declare module 'react-native-side-menu' {
  import { Component } from 'react'

  interface Props {}

  export default class SideMenu extends Component<Props> {}
}
```